# I can't return reviews' texts using selenium or BeautifulSoup or both combined for a dynamic website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape reviews from a dynamic website ([page](https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-2361428/%DA%AF%D9%88%D8%B4%DB%8C-%D9%85%D9%88%D8%A8%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%84-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%86%DA%AF-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84-galaxy-a51-sm-a515fdsn-%D8%AF%D9%88-%D8%B3%DB%8C%D9%85-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA-%D8%B8%D8%B1%D9%81%DB%8C%D8%AA-128%DA%AF%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA#/tab-comments/&page=1&order=most_liked)).
I've tried bellow codes but none of them return reviews.

**using BeautifulSoup:**

```
my_url = 'same above link'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = bs(page_html, "html.parser")
revs = page_soup.findAll("div", {"id":"product-comment-list"})

print(revs)
```

this code returns : `[]`

**Using Selenium:**

```
chrome_path = r"C:\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("same link above")

elm_revs = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-tab-name="comments"]')

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elm_revs)


try:
    revs = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "product-comment-list"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()

print(revs.text)

time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

this code returns: `urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=52205): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/63eeb4529f25314429dc7bf2926e010a/element/2ba52c02-56e8-4de8-8432-5e9148c2fcec/text (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000018BE37DE370>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))`

or if I use

```
try:
    revs = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "product-comment-list"))
    )
finally:
    print(revs.text)
```

it brings back nothing. just blank output!

**Using BeautifulSoup & Selenium combined:**

```
chrome_path = r"C:\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("same above link")


elm_revs = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-tab-name="comments"]')
page = driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elm_revs)


html = driver.page_source
page_soup = bs(html, "html.parser")

for tag in page_soup.findAll('id')
    print(tag.text)
```

and this one returns: `[]`

Comment: in your selenium answer you haven't accessed the .text. I also don't see that id.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues you have only one product comment and printing the element with .text.

```
revs = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "product-comment-list")))

print(revs.text)
```

Comment: thanks for reaching out, but I've tried this also and it brings me errors which I will put in Selenium part of the code.